# Форма записи try-catch

Tags: java

[Столкнулся с кодом](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/insert/):

```
    try (Connection conn = this.connect();
         PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
       pstmt.setString(1, name);
       pstmt.setDouble(2, capacity);
       pstmt.executeUpdate();
   } catch (SQLException e) {
       System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }
```

Почему `Connection conn = this.connect();...` записываются в скобках?
Она аналогична такой получается?

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
try {
    conn = this.connect();
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)
    pstmt.setString(1, name);
    pstmt.setDouble(2, capacity);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, не аналогична. Вот если вы в добавленном  блоке finaly закроете соединение, как это и положено делать , то тогда это будет аналогично. Первый вариант введен в `java 7` и называется `try-with-resources`. Идея заключается в том, что блок `try`, отображенный в таком виде, сам вызывает метод `close` у истребуемых ресурсов после того, как они отработали, что часто забывают делать, как вы сейчас, соответственно, это является причиной проблем.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: Не за что, старался короче и понятнее)

Answer (score -1):

Обязательно прочитайте доку [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/740455)